# How to write let expression with 'or' condition

Tags: alloy

While impleting the question A.3.6 on the book, I need to express a condition like:

> After putting on a glove, for the hand that the glove is on something happens while for gloves on the other hand should stay the same.

How can I express the condition neatly without specifying the conditions when glove is on the right hand and when the glove is on the left hand, since both conditions have the same structure.

My code is here: https://github.com/huanhulan/alloy-exercises/blob/master/book/appendixA/gloves.als#L137

Comment: The problem is clearly symmetric because you require 2 hands for an operation, why worry then about left and right? If you solve it for one hand then the other hand follows automatically?

Comment: @PeterKriens yes, that's exactly what I meant, sorry that can't explain the question more precisely. But doing so, I resulted in higher-order logics that alloy does not support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not an answer to your question directly, but I could not resist to make a simpler model than you seem to appear to work on. I generally do not use the `Time` model since it makes almost any problem unwieldy imho. If you go to this route, you might want to checkout [Electrum](https://github.com/haslab/Electrum2). This is a fork that hides the `Time` atom effectively and has nice keywords for constraining the past and future.

```
module austere_surgery

open util/relation
open util/ordering[Operation]

abstract sig Surface {}

abstract sig Human extends Surface {}
one sig Surgeon extends Human {}
sig Patient extends Human {}

sig Glove {
    inside   : disj Inside,
    outside  : disj Outside
} 
sig Inside, Outside extends Surface {}

sig Operation {
    patient  : disj Patient,
    -- surfaces is a path from surgeon -> glove* -> patient
    surfaces : Surface -> lone Surface,
    gloves   : set Glove,
    contaminated : Human-> Surface
} {
    -- constrain to be a proper path (could be improved)
    dom[surfaces] = Surgeon + (gloves.(inside+outside)-ran[surfaces])
    ran[surfaces] = patient + (gloves.(inside+outside)-dom[surfaces])
    all g : gloves | g.inside in dom[surfaces] iff g.outside in ran[surfaces]

    -- and no patient must come into contact with the blood of another patient. 
    surfaces.patient not in ran[contaminated - patient->Surface]

    -- the surgeon must not come into contact with the blood of any patient,
    Surgeon -> patient not in surfaces 
    Surgeon.surfaces not in Patient.contaminated
}

pred surgery {

    Surface = Glove.inside + Glove.outside + Human

    no first.contaminated

    all o' : Operation-first, o : o'.prev {

        o'.contaminated = o.contaminated 
            + o.touches[o.patient] 
            + o.touches[Surgeon]
            + o.touches[ran[o.contaminated-Surgeon->Surface]]   
    }
}

fun Operation.touches[ dirty : set Surface ] : (Patient+Surgeon)-> Surface {
    { from : dirty, to : Surface | from->to in this.surfaces or to->from in this.surfaces }
}


-- A surgeon must operate on three patients, but xe has only two pairs of gloves.
run surgery for 10 but exactly 3 Patient, exactly 3 Operation, exactly 2 Glove
```

A solution:

```
┌──────────────┬─────────────────┬────────┬──────┬─────────────────┐
│this/Operation│surfaces         │patient │gloves│contaminated     │
├──────────────┼────────┬────────┼────────┼──────┼─────────────────┤
│Operation⁰    │Inside⁰ │Inside¹ │Patient²│Glove⁰│                 │
│              ├────────┼────────┼────────┼──────┤                 │
│              │Outside¹│Patient²│        │Glove¹│                 │
│              ├────────┼────────┤        ├──────┤                 │
│              │Surgeon⁰│Outside⁰│        │      │                 │
├──────────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼──────┼────────┬────────┤
│Operation¹    │Inside⁰ │Patient¹│Patient¹│Glove¹│Patient²│Outside¹│
│              ├────────┼────────┼────────┼──────┼────────┼────────┤
│              │Surgeon⁰│Outside⁰│        │      │Surgeon⁰│Outside⁰│
├──────────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼──────┼────────┼────────┤
│Operation²    │Inside⁰ │Outside¹│Patient⁰│Glove⁰│Patient¹│Inside⁰ │
│              ├────────┼────────┼────────┼──────┼────────┼────────┤
│              │Inside¹ │Patient⁰│        │Glove¹│Patient²│Outside¹│
│              ├────────┼────────┤        ├──────┼────────┼────────┤
│              │Surgeon⁰│Outside⁰│        │      │Surgeon⁰│Outside⁰│
└──────────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴──────┴────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer really is a paradigm shift to me! BTW I used the `Time` to model the question simply because the exercise recommended me that way.

Comment: Yes, your solution is much clear than mine, and quicker for Alloy to find out, thank you again : )

Comment: If you like the response, you should mark it as the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

One option is to write the formula inside a predicate, and then pass in the part that varies between instantiations (in this case the relation that leftHand and rightHand are bound to).

Comment: I know what you mean, that result in higher order expressions which alloy doesn't support.